# bsimagepicker Terminated due to memory issue

Tags: ios, swift, picker

I am using `Bsimagepicker` for multiple selection of images from the gallery. `Bsimagepicker` is working for small size images, When try to load high quality image with large size leads to

> "Terminated due to memory issue"

Here is my code:

```
 var SelectedAssets = [PHAsset]()
 var PhotoArray = [UIImage]()

 @objc func opengallery(_ sender: AnyObject!){
    let vc = BSImagePickerViewController()
    self.bs_presentImagePickerController(vc, animated: true, select: { (asset: PHAsset)  -> Void in}, deselect: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in }, cancel: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
        let a = 1
        print("hello \(a)") }, finish: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
            self.imgc = assets.count
        for i in 0..<assets.count
        {
            self.SelectedAssets.append(assets[i])
        }

        self.convertAssetToImages()

    }, completion: guest)
 }


 func convertAssetToImages() -> Void{

    if SelectedAssets.count != 0{
        flaggalleryin = 2
        for i in 0..<SelectedAssets.count{

            let manager = PHImageManager.default()
            let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
            var thumbflag = 0
            var thumbnail = UIImage()
            option.isSynchronous = true
            var wid :Int!
            var hei :Int!
            if(SelectedAssets[i].pixelWidth > 750){
                wid = 700
            }else{
                wid = SelectedAssets[i].pixelWidth
            }
            if(SelectedAssets[i].pixelHeight > 750){
                hei = 700
            }else{
                hei = SelectedAssets[i].pixelHeight
            }
            manager.requestImage(for: SelectedAssets[i], targetSize: CGSize(width: wid, height: hei), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
                if(result != nil) {
                    thumbnail = result!
                    thumbflag = 1
                }else{
                    thumbflag = 0
                }
            })
            let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbnail, 1.0)
            let newImage = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.PhotoArray.append(newImage! as UIImage)

        }
    }
```

Please help me to resolve the Terminated due to memory issue

Thanks

Comment: Any Solution Get?